# Microsoft Identity Platform - User Token Cache args.Account is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an MVC web application wanting to send emails from one email address using Office365. I am calling the API so that it shows up the microsoftonline login page for signing in. On successful sign in I am receiving the code back from API and generating `Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult` with the help of code and saving `tokenresponse.UniqueId` and `tokenresponse.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier` in database.

I got to following page and signed in successfully and my database has the response saved.
[image: Sign In Page]
After this I am trying to send emails using following code:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication mailer;

            var mailerbuilder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                        .Create(o365setpQry.ClientId))
                                        .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, o365setpQry.Tenant)
                                        .WithClientSecret(o365setpQry.ClientSecret);

            mailerbuilder.WithRedirectUri(O365OAuthRedirectURL);
            mailer = mailerbuilder.Build();                


            //user token cache.
            mailer.UserTokenCache.SetAfterAccess((args) => {

                Users user;
                if **(args.Account == null)** user = null;
                else user = _users.Table.Where(x => x.email_address == args.Account.Username).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user == null)
                {
                    var emsetp = _emsetp.Table.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (args.HasStateChanged || (emsetp.o365_GlobalTokenInfo == null))
                    {
                        emsetp.o365_GlobalTokenInfo = args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3();
                    }
                }
                else if (args.HasStateChanged || (user.o365_TokenInfo == null))
                {
                    user.o365_TokenInfo = args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3();
                    _users.Update(user);
                }

            });
            webEmailer.UserTokenCache.SetBeforeAccess((args) => {
                Users user;
                **if (args.Account == null)** user = null;
                else  user = _users.Table.Where(x => x.email_address == args.Account.Username).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user == null)
                {
                    args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(_emsetp.Table.FirstOrDefault().o365_GlobalTokenInfo);
                }
                else if (user.o365_TokenInfo != null)
                {
                    args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(user.o365_TokenInfo);
                }
            });

var t = mailer.GetAccountAsync(emsetp.FirstOrDefault().o365_GlobalToken);
                        t.Wait();
                        Microsoft.Identity.Client.IAccount acct = t.Result;
```

The args.Account is returning null always.

```
var RequestClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(new AuthenticateRequestAsyncDelegate((args) => {
                var tokenRequest = mailer.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, acct).ExecuteAsync();
                tokenRequest.Wait();
                args.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenRequest.Result.AccessToken);
                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
            })));

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(RequestClient);

            var t = graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request();
            var u = t.PostAsync();
```

I made sure my redirect urls are matching and I am not getting any errors from the API calls to see what is wrong and what makes args.Account value null and thus am not able to send emails. If I request the sign in page again it still shows the account I am signed in with.